# '== was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, set

This problem is probably quite simple, but it has had me stumped for AGES.

Whenever I make a  `set /p choice` in my batch files, it seems to work fine. You type in your command and it goes to whichever command you entered in. But, whenever characters like spaces and >s and |s are accidentally put in, it says `(errorentered)'=='(first option)' was unexpected at this time` and then the program exits. I am making a game with batch files now and it is a pain if it does something like that. How do I stop it from exiting when there is such an error?

EXAMPLE:
Input: `connect a`

Output: `a'=='help' was unexpected at this time`
* program exits *

The code I am working with so far:

```
    @echo off
    :start
    cls
    color 0a
    echo                            Mandibles Game Hack Tool
    echo ================================================================================
    :blank
    set /p choice= %ipname%]
    if '%choice%'=='help' goto help
    if '%choice%'=='connect' goto connect
    if '%choice%'=='disconnect' goto disconnect
    if '%choice%'=='cls' goto start
    if '%choice%'=='exit' goto exit
    if '%choice%'=='crack' goto crack
    if '%choice%'=='download' goto download
    goto blank
```

And no, this is nowhere near real hacking. It's just a game.

Comment: change single quotes in IF conditions with double ones.

Comment: Have you tried using double-quotes instead?

Comment: and you use delayed expansion for more robust results.

Comment: I thought it'd be that easy, the double quotes worked fine thanks for all the help. :)